# using jquery 'this' to condense code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try not to ask questions, but I can't figure out what should be very easy. I'm building a site for practice briannabaldwinphotography.com. I'm just trying to condense this so that I could just click on an anchor and it smooth scrolls to a `<section>` with an id the same name as the anchor. Ex: the 'about' li anchor has an href of `#section_three` and will scroll to the `<section>` with an id of `section_three`. I tried like 10 different variations and it won't work for me. Sort of what I'm looking for would be `$(this).attr("href").offest().top}`....etc. Here is the code I want to condense. Thanks.

```
$(function() {
    $("[href='#section_three']").on("click", function() {
        $("html body").animate({"scrollTop":$("#section_three").offset().top}, 1000);
        return false;

    });
    $("[href='#section_two']").on("click", function() {
        $("html body").animate({"scrollTop":$("#section_two").offset().top}, 1000);
        return false;


    });
    $("[href='#section_four']").on("click", function() {
        $("html body").animate({"scrollTop":$("#section_four").offset().top}, 1000);
        return false;


    });
    $("[href='#section_one']").on("click", function() {
        $("html body").animate({"scrollTop":$("#section_one").offset().top}, 1000);
        return false;


    });

});
```

Comment: "I try not to ask questions" - why, just ask... :) Btw, $(this).attr('href') should help... and 'a' selector, i guess (without seeing your HTML)...

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [attribute starts with selector (`^=`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) you can get all elements with an href beginning with `"#section_"`, bind a handler to those, then within the handler use `this.href` to get the href of the particular element that was clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $("[href^='#section_']").on("click", function() {
        $("html body").animate({"scrollTop" : $(this.href).offset().top}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note that `this.href` does the same job as `$(this).attr("href")`, but more efficiently: no need to create a jQuery object to access a property of the element that you can get to directly.

Comment: actually `this.href` returns full absolute url with protocol, domain etc... `this.hash` would work though

Comment: That is a good idea using the 'attribute starts with' and using this.href instead of creating a jquery object. The code though doesn't seem to be working.... but its okay the other commenter has similar code that works. Thank you.

Comment: this.hash does ideed make the second commenter's code work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `href` in each case matches the target element it makes it fairly simple

```
$("[href^='#section']").on("click", function() {
        var targetSelector = $(this).attr('href');
        $("html body").animate({"scrollTop":$(targetSelector).offset().top}, 1000);
        return false;   
});
```

If those elements have a common class or better path through parent class and tags you could improve the initial selector performance

Comment: Works great thanks. I didn't think to try $($(this).attr('href')).offset()....... because this doesn't work $(this).attr('href').